# 'JWPlayer-iOS-SDK/JWPlayerController.h' file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, media-player, jwplayer

Followed the steps given at :https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/ios/docs/developer-guide/intro/getting-started/ to import JWPlayer

For troubleshooting: https://developer.jwplayer.com/sdk/ios/docs/developer-guide/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/

Also installed cocoapods and in Podfile added: pod 'JWPlayer-SDK', '~> 2.4.3'

ran pod install command later.

[image: Framework search path]

[image: Linked framework]

[image: Other linker flags field]

[image: Added license in JWPlayerKey]

[image: Hierarchy]

What am I missing?

Comment: Changed the import statement from
 #import <JWPlayer-iOS-SDK/JWPlayerController.h> to
 #import <JWPlayerController.h>

Getting the error:
ld: framework not found JWPlayer-iOS-SDK
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why, but after installing the SDK via cocoa pods, the import that ended up working for me was the following.

`#import <JWPlayer_iOS_SDK/JWPlayerController.h>`

Answer (score 1):

By **cocoa pod** installation you must use below path to import:

```
#import <JWPlayer-SDK/JWPlayerController.h>
```

And by adding framework it is said at document this path:

```
#import <JWPlayer-iOS-SDK/JWPlayerController.h>
```

> **But I faced *Not Found Error* by adding framework to project**
>
> **By pod installation app run without any error**

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with demo app. Simply removed the framework folder reference from the project (it wasn't there in the first place if you check the files in finder). Download the jwplayer framework. Drop it where the other files related to the app are and simply import it to your project in Xcode. After that just run the project. Voila it works.