# ld: framework not found JWPlayer-iOS-SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, jwplayer

[image]

I am trying to import JWPlayer but even after setting all the paths I am facing issues. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Relevant post: ['JWPlayer-iOS-SDK/JWPlayerController.h' file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39141851/jwplayer-ios-sdk-jwplayercontroller-h-file-not-found)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['JWPlayer-iOS-SDK/JWPlayerController.h' file not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39141851/jwplayer-ios-sdk-jwplayercontroller-h-file-not-found)

Comment: Copy the framework in your project path after do this import the framework from project path.

Comment: I added the exact path in "/Users/asthagupta/Downloads/jwplayer-ios-2.4.3+74/Framework/JWPlayer-iOS-SDK.framework" but again xcode is not able to find the framework :(

Comment: @SaurabhJain the framework is already present in my project path, right? The second line in the image I attached

Comment: Right click on your project name in Xcode after that click on show in finder and paste your framework here. If you already done this then import another framework similar to this and check find is xcode find this framework or not.

Comment: Copied the framework in my workspace. Again the same error

Comment: Restart your X-code and again check.

Comment: Done that thrice :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121896/discussion-between-saurabh-jain-and-astha-gupta).

Comment: The last option you can use Drag the framework in your project and make sure copy item if needed is cheked.

Comment: @AsthaGupta have you solved the error?

Comment: Where is this option present?

Comment: @AsthaGupta In my last comment.

Comment: check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39141851/jwplayer-ios-sdk-jwplayercontroller-h-file-not-found/42361935#42361935